# Playframework app including a standalone main application

Tags: java, playframework, program-entry-point, playframework-2.2

I am writing a webapp with Playframework 2.2 in Java. 
Now I want to add a small standalone text-to-database-import tool, which consists of only one Java file with a `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  importTextToDatabase();
}
```

- Can I include this standalone mini-app together with the rest of the webapp?
- How can I then run it in the `activator` (or `sbt`) (without the webapp)?
- Or is it better to create a second project for this app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured this out a few months ago and forgot. Just took me two hours to figure it out again. The answer is run-main. The trick is you need quotes around run-main and the parameters that follow it or it will give you an error. So...

If you have a class my.package.Main your would run it with:

`play "run-main my.package.Main"`

I believe you can also run it directly from sbt with a similar command:

`sbt "run-main my.package.Main"`

Newer versions of `sbt` requires:
`sbt "runMain my.package.Main"`

Comment: Great, thanks for your two hours ;-). Works also in the `activator`.

Answer (score 3):

Applicable for Play 2.3

In stage and dist environment, there is a startup script named the same as the project name in the `bin` directory. In that script, there is a `app_mainclass` variable specifying the main class to be executed by the script. You can copy the generated script and replace the definition of the main class variable to run your own *main*. With that, you can use the other built-in goodies of the script to pass extra parameters to the JVM, setup debug port, and specify your main program arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I had very similar problem pretty recently and it appears that Play Framework have this issue already addressed. It works perfectly fine with version 2.5.x. I am not sure if that was available in previous versions though.

Basically, execution of `stage` command should generate Linux and DOS/Windows launcher scripts (in `target/target/universal/stage/bin` directory). When you run that script with option `-h`, you should get all execution parameters. One of them is:

```
-main <classname>  Define a custom main class
```

So that way you can run standalone applications (e.g. ./target/universal/stage/bin/your-app -main com.your.Application), which have access to the same libraries or configuration as your Play web server.